# Why does ApplicationStart timeout with AWS code deploy?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am using codedeploy to deploy a springboot app to an ec2. But I keep getting a script timeout error. I event set the timeout to 60 seconds event tho the application always starts up within 20 seconds. The application starts up fine. I run `top` on the linux instance and see the java process started up. I can then use postman to hit the http status check endpoint and confirm that it has started up successfully. But this is what it looks like in the code deploy console:

[image]

The appspec.yml file looks like this

[image]

The server_start.sh file looks like this.
[image]

Why is this happening? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to start the application as a service / daemon / in the background. Otherwise the scripts after the application ends.

Comment: have the same issue where application starts and works but then script times out and the application stops as well. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I think this has more to do with how Linux process works than with Code Build. I'm far from being a specialist on that, but according to with AWS documentation, there is a certain way you must use to start your long-running processes, as a Java application

The syntax is:

```
#!/bin/bash
/tmp/sleep.sh > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &
```

Replace the sleep by your Java command.

[More details here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-deployments.html#troubleshooting-long-running-processes)

Answer (score 0):

You should put some some codes of your script to the **BeforeInstall** or **AfterInstall**.

**remove java -jar application.jar**

BeforeInstall – You can use this deployment lifecycle event for preinstall tasks, such as decrypting files and creating a backup of the current version. 
Install – During this deployment lifecycle event, the CodeDeploy agent copies the revision files from the temporary location to the final destination folder. This event is reserved for the CodeDeploy agent and cannot be used to run scripts. 
**AfterInstall – You can use this deployment lifecycle event for tasks such as configuring your application or changing file permissions.** 
ApplicationStart – You typically use this deployment lifecycle event to restart services that were stopped during ApplicationStop.

Then create another bash script for your ApplicationStart. Put the line your removed earlier on this script.